# Display server performance information in Asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, performance, monitor

I want to display the performance of the windows server 2008 (Memory Usage, CPU usage, Disk usage, Network Usage) in the asp.net website chart.

How to implement to display these information in asp.net real time like what we see in "Resource Monitor".

I have to monitor IIS and MSSQL database servers.

Do I need to write window service to send the performance info every second to website?

Will it effect the performance of the server? Any Idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always found the best result is to have a separate process write everything you need to know to a database and then have the website simply query that database. Opposed to having the web server get all of this information when requested. This way if you have more than 1 users refreshing the page it will not impact your servers beyond the expected impact of the polling process.